# openshot and ffmpeg get confused with an mts file with multiple audio

Tags: debian, audio, ffmpeg, codec

I used to cut recordings from my satelite receiver (mts files with one video and multiple audio streams) with `openshot`, but I have a problem since upgrading from good old debian jessie to buster:

- Converting the `mts` video and ac3 stream gives me a video with silent audio stream with only rare random noise
- Using the `mp2` audio stream of the `mts` instead works as expected
- Playing the `mts` video in `openshot` (which seems to use `ffmpeg` internally) gives wild noise with almost no relation to the correct audio stream
- I can isolate the video and ac3 stream with `ffmpeg -map 0:0 -map 0:4 -c copy` to another mts file, which I can open in `openshot` and hear the correct audio, unfortunally with a one-second-lag between video and audio
- `vlc` can play all audio streams of the video without problems
- The output doesn't show any obvious errors or warnings

The configuration is unmodified buster configuration:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
```

How to find out what goes wrong?

Comment: So playing for example this: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.ac3 - gives noise? [(From ESP Audio Samples)](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-adf/en/latest/design-guide/audio-samples.html). Also include log of for example: `ffplay -vn -nodisp -v 48 some_file.ac3`

Comment: No, this sample is fine. Even https://we.tl/wRwJ3EJt32 which is also ac3 5.1 like mine has no problem. I'll have a look where I can upload a sample which fails now but was okay on my good old debian Jessie.

Comment: The `-v 48` gives debug information.

Comment: Rather confusing: I also have no problems with `ffplay` if I choose the said stream with `-ast 4`. Then I used `ffmpeg` with `-map 0:0 -map 0:4 -c copy` to isolate only the video and the ac3 stream and I could open the result in `openshot` without any problem. But if I `-c -copy` all streams, the problem occurs. It's like the audio codecs get mixed up in a multi-stream mts. I happens to all mts files recorded by my satelite receiver. I can provide a sample, but where can I make it available to you?